# Why Oracle type created by one user is not visible by another user?

Tags: database, oracle, rights-management

I have 2 users in OracleXE db: `ALICE` and `BOB`. Following sequence of steps is successful at my local machine:

- connect as `ALICE`
- create top-level type: `create or replace type testtype as object(x number(16));` *(EDIT: correction from wrong name foo which misleaded Matthew McPeak)*
- connect as `BOB`
- `BOB` sees the `ALICE`'s type:

  - `select * from all_types` returns row
  - `declare x ALICE.testtype; begin null; end;` compiles

Same steps applied to our development database yield in situation where type is invisible to `BOB`, i.e. select doesn't return row for the type, PLSQL block compilation fails with `PLS-00201: identifier 'ALICE.TESTTYPE' must be declared` error.

I need to make type visible, so I ask: *What may cause this difference?* (I guessed for some need of grants on types or public synonyms, however this minimalistic example proves the opposite.) Some property of user/session? I did my best in googling and am stuck now though I hope the solution will be trivial. Both databases are Oracle 11g (11.2.0.1.0 dev, 11.2.0.2.0 local).

Thanks!

Comment: likely that Bob and Alice have different roles and rights from one database to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming it's more than just the fact that you named your type `foo` but tried to use it as `testtype`.

If `foo` is the correct name, then, as `ALICE`:

```
grant execute on foo to bob;
```

Bob probably has `EXECUTE ANY TYPE` or similar system privilege in the 1st database.

Comment: Sorry, foo was wrong, I overlooked this typo when rewriting from mail. Thnks, I will try it on my work computer soon.

Comment: Solved. At my local machine, Bob has been created by system user and initialized by script which comes from this query: `select 'grant ' || privilege || ' to BOB' from session_privs`. Hence he really had `EXECUTE ANY TYPE` privilege. After restricting privileges, everything went back to normal and `grant execute on TESTTYPE to BOB`/`revoke execute on TESTTYPE from BOB` enables/disables access, respectively.